# google docs viewer wont keep the margins of the document

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

Hello i have a file that on Libreoffice calc the print preview fits on the page 
but on google docs viewer slits on the width of the page, 
I think there is some margin issue.
The file was created with openpyxl.
and i've used

```
ws.sheet_properties.pageSetUpPr.fitToPage = True
```

option
[image: This is how it looks on the print preview]
[image]